# paperjs events on multiple canvases

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm trying to understand how paperjs works with multiple canvases. I'd like to have two different canvases to work on two different images at the same time. Right now I'm stuck on how events are managed.

```
window.onload = function() {
    paper.install(window);
    var mypapers = [];

    initPaper(0, $("#canvas1")[0]);
    //initPaper(1, $("#canvas2")[0]);

    function initPaper(id, canvasElement) {
        mypapers[id] = new PaperScope();
        paper = mypapers[id];
        paper.activate();
        paper.setup(canvasElement);

        // Create a raster item using the image tag with id='mona'
        var raster = new paper.Raster('mona');
        raster.position = new paper.Point(raster.width / 2 + 2, raster.height / 2 + 2);

        var pointLayer = new Layer();
        pointLayer.activate(); 

        paper.view.onMouseUp = onMouseUp(event);

    }
    /////////////////////////////////////
    function onMouseUp(event) {
        console.log('mouseup');
    }
};
```

I am still confused on the difference between inline paperscript and javascript. It took me a while to be able to use an external js file instead of having all inline (canvas not defined). Right now I'd like to see the "mouseup" every time i click the mousebutton, but instead I see it only once. I'd like to be able to make it work with the two canvases and I also would like to be able to define each funtion once instead of writing the same code for every canvas.

A different approach works:

```
paper.install(window);

window.onload = function() {

var mypapers = [];

initPaper(0, $("#canvas1")[0]);
//initPaper(1, $("#canvas2")[0]);

function initPaper(id, canvasElement) {
    mypapers[id] = new paper.PaperScope();
    paper = mypapers[id];
    paper.setup(canvasElement);

    // Create a raster item using the image tag with id='mona'
    var raster = new paper.Raster('mona');
    raster.position = new paper.Point(raster.width / 2 + 2, raster.height / 2 + 2);

    paper.view.onMouseUp = function(event) { console.log('mouseup'+id);}


}
};
```

This version does indeed work but then I can't have a single method to manage all mouseups.

edit [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vs4v9y0m/)

Comment: Can you include a Code Snippet, or CodePen?

Comment: There are two main differences between paperscript and JavaScript. With paperscript paper objects are available globally - `new Path(..)` vs. `new paper.Path(...)`. The second difference is the ability to use operators ('-', '+', etc.) with Points(). You must have paper-full installed to use paperscript -in runs a parser on load to accomplish the operator overloading.

Comment: @arthur.sw jsfiddle added. the image is not mine but i'm sure it will behave the same way as the original locally stored jpg

Comment: @bmacnaughton thanks. I think that is not the reason my code doesn't work thugh.

Comment: Agree, you noted you weren't clear on the difference; that is why I made the comment.

Answer (score 2):

In your first code example, you are making an error when trying to bind the event handler.
When you do:

```
paper.view.onMouseUp = onMouseUp(event);
```

You are actually assigning the return value of the call `onMouseUp(event)` to `paper.view.onMouseUp` property.
That's why you only see the console log one time on load and why nothing happen then.
What you want to do instead is:

```
paper.view.onMouseUp = onMouseUp;
```

About the other part of your question, here is a simplified example showing you how you can use the same named function to handle events on different canvas through different `PaperScope` instances.
Click on both canvas and see the console logs.

```js
// install paper in the current scope so we can directly use PaperScope, Raster...
paper.install(window);

// init paper on both canvases
initPaper('canvas1');
initPaper('canvas2');

function initPaper(canvasId) {
  // create a new scope
  var scope = new PaperScope();
  // set it up on provided canvas
  scope.setup(canvasId);
  // activate it so that newly created items will be created within this scope
  scope.activate();

  // create a raster
  var raster = new Raster('image');
  // position it at view center
  raster.position = scope.view.center;

  // bind external handler to view mouse up event
  scope.view.onMouseUp = onMouseUp;
}

// external handler used for both canvases
function onMouseUp(event) {
  console.log('mouseup');
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

canvas {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/paper.js/0.11.5/paper-core.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <canvas id="canvas1" resize></canvas>
  <canvas id="canvas2" resize></canvas>
</main>

<img id="image" src="http://placehold.it/120x120&text=image1"></img>
```